# What does the position number mean in this UnicodeError : 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 2196”

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, binary-data

It often occurs to me when I try to manipulate data, for example **"UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 2196: illegal multibyte sequence".**

I have found a way to bypass this error but my curiosity drives me to investigate what is in position 2196.

#### **Here comes the question**:

How to understand the number 2196? I mean what encoding should I use when I counting from 1,2,...,2196. utf-8? gbk? binary? hex or sth else?
And how can I see the number in that position without throwing error?

**Here is a code portion as an example:**

```
with open(r"G:\ETCData\6aMTC\2019-06-01.txt", "r") as fp:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp):
        if i == 6:
            pass

UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6810d8c84b34> in <module>()
      1 with open(r"G:\ETCData\6aMTC\2019-06-01.txt", "r") as fp:
----> 2     for i, line in enumerate(fp):
      3         if i == 6:
      4             pass

UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 2196: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Comment: Why don't you print every line to see which one causes it? (Obviously, it will be the line after last printed.)

Comment: What I found - https://www.charbase.com/0091-unicode-private-use-one It's a bytecode of a character that is not used in the unicode itself?

Comment: Open the file in a hex editor en see where the 91 byte is.

Comment: @h4z3 It's a really big file with more than 1million lines :(  Anyway, you inspired me. I manually do a binary-tree search to locate that line, no. 152866. I'm working on it using code comparison tool.

Comment: So maybe count the number of lines instead of printing the line itself? Then you can grab the line in the console. Or find whether grep can accept character's code/byte and search by it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here, is that the decoding function is called from the internals of the io system. 2196 is the position of the offending byte in the read buffer. If your file was short enough to be read in a single chunk, or if the error occured on the first chunk, then it is the position of the byte in the file. In any other case, it will be hard to guess the real position of the byte in the file.

BTW `b'\x91'` is the LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK unicode U+2018 `‘` in the cp1252 charset.

Comment: A quick, accurate and brilliant answer. By the way, how do you know b'\x91' is the left quotation mark in cp1252, from an online dictionary or based on experience ?

Comment: @Ray.H: The module `unicodedata` from Python Standard Library is great to find the names of any unicode character. And cp1252 is the charset of my Windows box. I still know the ascii codes but not the full unicode list...

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the correct encoding when you open the file. Try adding this to the `open` command:

```
with open(r"G:\ETCData\6aMTC\2019-06-01.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp):
        if i == 6:
            pass
```

Re number 2196 - it's just saying that it can't read correctly a symbol in the position 2196. It's literally the position of the symbol in the line from the beginning of that line.

In order to see it, check what was the value of `line` during the error and open `txt` file with any text editor. Find the line and find the symbol.

Comment: 0x91 is illegal in utf8. Unsure of what the encoding can be, but it **cannot** be utf-8!

Comment: I omit talking about correct encoding to avoid losing focus.  Correct encoding is GBK, I can read staff names with GBK. But error still shown. I solved this by **using open("\path", "rb") instead of  open("path", "r").**  Then decode(encoding=‘GBK’) a byte object. 0 error, yes!